# Difference between a[len(a):] = [x] and a[len(a)] = [x]

Tags: python

Why is `a[len(a):] = [x]` equivalent to `a.append(x)`, but `a[len(a)] = [x]` gives an out of range error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) (emphasis mine):

> - If the target is a subscription: ...
>
>   If the primary is a mutable sequence object (such as a list), the subscript must yield a plain integer. If it is negative, the
>     sequence’s length is added to it. The resulting value must be a
>     nonnegative integer less than the sequence’s length, and the sequence
>     is asked to assign the assigned object to its item with that index.
>     **If the index is out of range, IndexError is raised (assignment to a subscripted sequence cannot add new items to a list)**
>
>   ...
> - If the target is a slicing: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield a mutable sequence object (such as a
>     list). The assigned object should be a sequence object of the same
>     type. Next, the lower and upper bound expressions are evaluated,
>     insofar they are present; defaults are zero and the sequence’s length.
>     The bounds should evaluate to (small) integers. If either bound is
>     negative, the sequence’s length is added to it. The resulting bounds
>     are clipped to lie between zero and the sequence’s length, inclusive.
>     Finally, the sequence object is asked to replace the slice with the
>     items of the assigned sequence. **The length of the slice may be
>     different from the length of the assigned sequence, thus changing the
>     length of the target sequence, if the object allows it.**

So assignment to a slice can change the length of the list, but assignment to an index (subscription) cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's an explicit choice the language made; assigning to indices requires those indices to exist. Assigning to slices will expand or contract the list as needed to accommodate a new size.

Answer (score 2):

Python's slicing is generally more "forgiving" than indexing with a number (by design).  For example:

```
lst = []
lst[1:100]  # No exception here.
```

I think that the slice assignment case is just an extension of this "forgivingness".  Interestingly enough, you can even use indices that are wildly out of range:

```
a = []
a[100:101] = ['foo']
```